# Laravel - Unable to cache the data

Tags: laravel

I want to cache some data in my Laravel Application. What I am doing is :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

$put = Cache::put('your_product', array(1,2,3,4), 3000 );
```

If I do `var_dump` I got `false` and Its not caching the data.

```
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $put );
echo '</pre>';
```

Is there another way to use the cache in laravel? Or I am doing wrong?

BTW, I am using latest laravel version.

Comment: please check this post
https://kinsta.com/blog/laravel-caching/

Comment: @MohammadEdrisRaufi i saw but can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: please try var_dump(Cache::get('your_product')) and let me know what you get

Comment: Its returning me an empty array.

Comment: please use dd like this  `dd(Cache::get('your_product'))` because i copied your code in my machine and it works fine

Comment: Yes I did exactly what you said but it's showng me now : `null`

Comment: I think I find the issue. I can see that there is no `CACHE_DRIVER` key in my `.env` file. I added it and now its working fine.

Comment: great it's really good that you found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [get](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#obtaining-a-cache-instance) method.

```
Cache::put('your_product', array(1,2,3,4), 3000);
dd(Cache::get('your_product'));
```